# Adjust amount of gaussian blur with bumpmap?

Tags: blur

Is it possible to somehow adjust the amount of gaussian blur with a bumpmap? For example: To set white to zero blur and black to x blur and have the blur increase along some curve between the two? I have an application where the cameras DOF can't achieve the effect I am after.

Comment: It might help to illustrate what are trying to if you added some images to your post. I would suggest one with your current setup and another with an approximation of how you want it to come out.

Comment: I don't really have anything useful to illustrate my question with. My initial idea was that since a bump-map is essentially a scale (from white to black) where every value is step/measurement, this could be used to also control blur. E.g. 0 = no blur, 255 = 10 pixels of blur. And the rest on a scale between these two. This would allow the aplication of more blur to details that are "further away/deeper".

Comment: I am not sure if this exists, but to make sure, I understand: the map you are speaking of is just a stand-alone, grayscale 8-bit image. And you want the pixel values of this image to drive the amount of blur on another flat image, like, say, with a compositor node?